# adding two integers to get a long in JAVA

Tags: java, long-integer

I have cracked my head enough and hence asking here:

This works:

```
int dummy_1, dummy_2;
long final_dummy;
dummy_1 = 0x12345678;
dummy_2 = 0x78563412;
final_dummy = (long)dummy_1 | (long)dummy_2<<32;
System.out.println(String.format("%08X", final_dummy));
```

Answer : 7856341212345678

This doesnt work:

```
int dummy_1, dummy_2;
long final_dummy;
dummy_1 = 0xB6F93000;
dummy_2 = 0xB6F93000;
final_dummy = (long)dummy_1 | (long)dummy_2<<32;
System.out.println(String.format("%08X", final_dummy));
```

Answer: FFFFFFFFB6F93000

Expected answer :  B6F93000B6F93000

Comment: Hint: print out `dummy_1` and `dummy_2` first. They're not the values you think they are. Look at the range of `int`. Also, your code would be easier to read if you followed Java naming conventions, and declared your variables at the point of first use.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 3):

`0xB6F93000` is actually the `int` value `-1225183232`. When coerced to `long`, it becomes `0xFFFFFFFFB6F93000L`, which is also `-1225183232`.

When you convert `int` to `long` you need to make it an unsigned conversion.

```
// In Java 8
int dummy_1 = 0xB6F93000;
int dummy_2 = 0xB6F93000;
long final_dummy = Integer.toUnsignedLong(dummy_1) | Integer.toUnsignedLong(dummy_2) << 32;

// In all Java versions
int dummy_1 = 0xB6F93000;
int dummy_2 = 0xB6F93000;
long final_dummy = (dummy_1 & 0xFFFFFFFFL) | (long)dummy_2 << 32;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code that doesn't work, your initial `dummy_1` and `dummy_2` values are negative; in Java, all numeric types are signed.  The highest bit is set, which is seen because the first hex digit is greater than or equal to 8.

Because these values are negative, when casted to a `long`, sign extension occurs.

```
0xB6F93000 => 0xFFFFFFFFB6F9000L
```

When logically ORed, those `F` digits remain, explaining why the most significant 8 hex digits (4 bytes) are `F`s instead of your value.

Use a mask to clear those sign-extended bits prior to ORing them.

```
final_dummy = (((long) dummy_1) & 0xFFFFFFFFL) | (((long)dummy_2) & 0xFFFFFFFFL) << 32;
```

This will clear the most significant 8 hex digits, as if sign extension did not take place.  With this change, I get:

```
B6F93000B6F93000
```

Bit-anding on `dummy_2` is not necessary, because the shift eliminates those 32 bits anyway.

```
final_dummy = (((long) dummy_1) & 0xFFFFFFFFL) | (long) dummy_2 << 32;
```

As an aside, normal Java naming conventions dictate that the variables names should be `dummy1`, `dummy2`, and `finalDummy`.

Comment: Also no need to cast `dummy_1` to `long`, since `int & long` will coerce the `int` to `long` implicitly.